# Playwright Webkit creates a "salt" file in the root of directory

Tags: webkit, playwright

I started writing autotests and noticed that playwright + webkit creates a "salt" file in the root of the directory with the tests. It does not interfere, but I would like to understand what it is for, why webkit does not clean up after itself, and whether it is possible to adjust generation of this file?

playwright.config browser settings

```
use: { 
    ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
},
```

To exclude any influence of the tests, in the spec, just go to the page

```
page.goto()
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/22048) in the playwright project.